Spring Boot Migrator - Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7
I am trying to migrate my springboot app from springboot 2.7.5 to 3.x using springboot migrator project. While trying to execute i get below exception stacktrace.
Scanning D:\\Project\\app-name
18:11:02.147 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:765)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:752)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
        at org.springframework.sbm.SpringBootUpgradeReportApp.main(SpringBootUpgradeReportApp.java:31)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: file://C:\Users\<username>\.m2\repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.7.5/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.7.5.pom
        at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:906)
        at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.download(MavenPomDownloader.java:487)
        at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom$Resolver.resolveParentPropertiesAndRepositoriesRecursively(ResolvedPom.java:353)
        at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom$Resolver.resolveParentsRecursively(ResolvedPom.java:310)
        at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom$Resolver.resolve(ResolvedPom.java:299)
        at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom.resolve(ResolvedPom.java:144)
        at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.Pom.resolve(Pom.java:104)
        at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenParser.parseInputs(MavenParser.java:122)
        at org.springframework.sbm.build.impl.RewriteMavenParser.parseInputs(RewriteMavenParser.java:92)
        at org.springframework.sbm.project.parser.MavenProjectParser.parse(MavenProjectParser.java:94)
        at org.springframework.sbm.project.parser.ProjectContextInitializer.initProjectContext(ProjectContextInitializer.java:52)
        at org.springframework.sbm.engine.commands.ScanCommand.execute(ScanCommand.java:70)
        at org.springframework.sbm.SpringBootMigratorRunner.run(SpringBootMigratorRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:762)
        ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: file://C:\Users\<username>\.m2\repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.7.5/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.7.5.pom
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2974)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(URI.java:3308)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3219)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3175)
        at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:623)
        at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:904)
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:765)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:752)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
        at org.springframework.sbm.SpringBootUpgradeReportApp.main(SpringBootUpgradeReportApp.java:31)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: file://C:\Users\<username>\.m2\repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.7.5/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.7.5.pom
        at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:906)
        at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.download(MavenPomDownloader.java:487)
        at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom$Resolver.resolveParentPropertiesAndRepositoriesRecursively(ResolvedPom.java:353)
        at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom$Resolver.resolveParentsRecursively(ResolvedPom.java:310)
        at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom$Resolver.resolve(ResolvedPom.java:299)
        at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom.resolve(ResolvedPom.java:144)
        at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.Pom.resolve(Pom.java:104)
        at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenParser.parseInputs(MavenParser.java:122)
        at org.springframework.sbm.build.impl.RewriteMavenParser.parseInputs(RewriteMavenParser.java:92)
        at org.springframework.sbm.project.parser.MavenProjectParser.parse(MavenProjectParser.java:94)
        at org.springframework.sbm.project.parser.ProjectContextInitializer.initProjectContext(ProjectContextInitializer.java:52)
        at org.springframework.sbm.engine.commands.ScanCommand.execute(ScanCommand.java:70)
        at org.springframework.sbm.SpringBootMigratorRunner.run(SpringBootMigratorRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:762)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: file://C:\Users\<username>\.m2\repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.7.5/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.7.5.pom
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2974)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(URI.java:3308)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3219)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3175)
        at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:623)
        at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:904)
        ... 26 more

Since .m2 is generated when the app is built not sure what is issue of the file generated. Tried even deleting the .m2 folder and build again, but nothing worked.
